# C# LINQ to SQL - one to many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I have troubles creating this query in LINQ:

```
USE Northwind
GO

SELECT emp.FirstName, emp.LastName, tr.TerritoryDescription, reg.RegionDescription
FROM Employees emp
INNER JOIN EmployeeTerritories empt ON empt.EmployeeID = emp.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN Territories tr ON tr.TerritoryID = empt.TerritoryID
INNER JOIN Region reg ON reg.RegionID = tr.RegionID
```

This is my current creation:

```
var query = await context
                .Employees
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.FirstName,
                    x.LastName,
                    TerritoryId = x.EmployeeTerritories. //cannot access properties
                })
                .ToListAsync();
```

But i can't easily access `EmployeeTerritories` properties, since it's not 1:1 relationship. I accept both clues and full solution to this problem.

Edit

So this is what i currently have:

```
            var query = await context
            .Employees
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.FirstName,
                x.LastName,
                TerritoryDescription = x.EmployeeTerritories
                    .Select(et => et.Territory.TerritoryDescription)
                    .ToList(),
                RegionDesicription = x.EmployeeTerritories
                    .Select(et => et.Territory.Region.RegionDescription)
                    .ToList()
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

Is there a way to optimize it? `RegionDescription` is now a `list` that contains one element, but i don't know how to do it the better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (assuming you have corresponding relations):

```
var query = await context
            .Employees
            .Select(x => new
            {
                x.Employee.FirstName,
                x.Employee.LastName,
                TerritoryDescription = x.EmployeeTerritories
                    .Select(et => et.Territory.TerritoryDescription)
                    .ToList(),
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

**UPD**

To flatten in your particular case you can use solution posted by [@dhrumil shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4106124/dhrumil-shah)(it is more generic one) or try something like that, if you have `EmployeeTerritories` set up in your context :

```
var query = await context
            .EmployeeTerritories
            .Select(et => new
                    {
                        et.Employee.FirstName,
                        et.Employee.LastName,
                        et.Territory.TerritoryDescription,
                        et.Territory.Region.RegionDescription
                    })
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Ok this can potentially work, i have created the rest (Region) identical way. But now im thinking how to display it, since its a `list` with two `lists` inside. Rather unusual thing (at least for me).

Comment: @AdmiralCat3 you can use `SelectMany` to flatten list. or `string.Join` to turn list into `string`. Also what is second list?

Comment: Ah right, picking different starting point would be better. But what if i WANT to use my solution? Is there a way to adjust it, or always the most optimal starting point should be picked?

Comment: @AdmiralCat3 first of all i would change `TerritoryDescription` to `x.EmployeeTerritories.Select(et => new  {et.Territory.TerritoryDescription, et.Region.RegionDescription}).ToList(),` after that it depends on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

```
(from emp in context.Employees 

 join empt in context.EmployeeTerritories 
 on emp.EmployeeID equals empt.EmployeeID
 
 join tr in context.EmployeeTerritories 
 on empt.TerritoryID equals tr.EmployeeID 
 
 join reg in context.Region 
 on reg.RegionID equals tr.RegionID 
 
 select new { 
 emp.FirstName, 
 emp.LastName, 
 tr.TerritoryDescription, 
 reg.RegionDescription
 }).ToList();
```